# pytest- how to raise Assertion Error?

Tags: python, exception, pytest

I am writing a few test cases for a project. In my project an "Address" object MUST contain a set of 3 attributes, either a 'name','email','phone' or 'address','city','state_id'.

```
@observes('name', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'city',
              'states_id', 'state')
    def validate_address_obj(self, name, email, phone, address, city,
                             states_id, state):
        name_email_phone = name and email and phone
        address_city_state = address and city and (states_id or state)

        if not name_email_phone and not address_city_state:
            raise AssertionError(
                "A valid address has to have: {} AND/OR {} defined.".format(
                    "name, email, and phone", "address, city, and state"))
        # fi
    # end def validate_address_obj
```

This function validates that a set of attributes is present, if the required attributes are not present an 'AssertionError' should be raised. When i run my tests, no exceptions are raised.

```
def test_validate_addresses(address_factory):
    """ An Address must consist of at least: a name, phone number, and email OR
      an address, city, and state """

    # Testing name, email, and phone need to be set
    # when address, city, and states_id is not

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(name='', address='', city='', state=None)

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(email='', address='', city='', state=None)

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(phone='', address='', city='', state=None)

    # Testing address, city, and states_id need to be set
    # when name, email, and phone is not

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(address='', name='', email='', phone='')

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(city='', name='', email='', phone='')

    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
      address_factory(state=None, name='', email='', phone='')

# end def test_validate_addresses
```

This is a snippet of my Test Case.

Comment: Are you familiar with `assert` statements?

Comment: yes i am. ex. assert 1 == 1 , will pass! @Joel

Comment: What happens when you type in `assert 1 == 2`?

Comment: the test fails @Joel

Comment: Exactly. An `AssertionError` is raised, which is what you want, correct? You can apply this to your code with `assert name_email_phone and address_city_state, "Error message"`

Comment: with pytest.raises(Exception) as cm:
      address_factory(name=None, address=None, city=None, state=None)
    assert "A valid address has to have: name, email, and phone AND/OR address, city, and state defined." == str(cm.value) @Joel